# How to read a file into an array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

Im trying to read a text file into an array of structs, but when trying to print the array, the struct is empty. The printing function works fine and I think the problem is in getRawData.

```
struct student
{
    char ID[MAXID + 1];
    char f_name[FIRST_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    char s_name[LAST_NAME_LENGTH + 1];
    int points[MAXROUNDS];
};
```

```
//main//

case 'W':
      if(save(array, len) == 0);
      {
           printf("Data saved.\n");
      }     
      break;
case 'O':
      if(getRawData(array, len));
      {
            printf("File read.\n");
      }
      break;
```

```
int save(struct student *h, int num_students)
{
    char name[20];
    printf("Enter file name: " );
    scanf("%s", name); // Read in filename
    FILE *output = fopen(name, "w"); // open the file to write
    if (!output) {
        return -1; // error
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_students; ++i)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%s %s %s \n", h[i].f_name, h[i].s_name, h[i].ID);
        for(int j = 0; j < MAXROUNDS; j++)
        {

            fprintf(output, "%d\n", h[i].points[j]);
        }
        printf("Information of student %s %s (%s) written into file %s\n", h[i].s_name, h[i].f_name, h[i].ID, name);

    }
    fclose(output); // close
    return 0;
}
int getRawData(struct student *records)
{
    int i;
    int nmemb; // amount of structs
    char name[20];
    printf("Name of the file to be opened: \n");
    scanf("%s", name);
    FILE *outtput = fopen(name, "r");
    int ch=0;
    int lines=0; 

    if (outtput == NULL);
        return 0;

    lines++;
    while(!feof(outtput))  
    {
        ch = fgetc(outtput);
        if(ch == '\n')
        {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    nmemb = lines / 7;
    for(i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
        fscanf(outtput, "%s %s %s", records[i].f_name, records[i].s_name, records[i].ID);
        for(int j = 0; j < MAXROUNDS; j++)
        {

            fscanf(outtput, "%d\n", &records[i].points[j]);
        }
    }
    printf("%d", lines);
    return i;
}
```

So my goal is to get the data from the file and write it over whatever there is stored in the struct array. I would appreciate some help as I have been working on this for way too long.

Comment: Post the rest of the `main` function.

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong).  You read to EOF of `outputt`, and then proceed to try to read more from it without either rewinding or closing and reopening it.  If you tested the return value from `fscanf()`, you'd spot this problem.

Comment: Better store your thing in a textual format like [JSON](http://json.org/) and use libraries related to that format

Answer (score 2):

Look at this code in `getRawData()`, first you are reading file to identify total number of lines:

```
    while(!feof(outtput))  
    {
        ch = fgetc(outtput);
        if(ch == '\n')
        .....
        .....
```

due to this the file stream pointer pointing to `EOF` and after this, in the `for` loop, you are doing:

```
    for(i = 0; i < nmemb; i++) {
        fscanf(outtput, "%s %s %s", records[i].f_name, records[i].s_name, records[i].ID);
        .....
        .....
```

Here, the `fscanf()` must be returning the `EOF` because there is nothing remain to read from stream file. You should check the return value of `fscanf()` while reading file.

You should reset the pointer to start of file before reading it again. You can use either `rewind(ptr)` or `fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_SET)`. Below is a sample program to show you what is happening in your code and how the solution works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
        int ch;
        int lines = 0;
        char str[100];
        FILE *fptr = fopen ("file.txt", "r");

        if (fptr == NULL) {
                fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open file");
                return -1;
        }

        while (!feof(fptr)) {
                ch = fgetc (fptr);
                if(ch == '\n') {
                        lines++;
                }
        }

        printf ("Number of lines in file: %d\n", lines);
        printf ("ch : %d\n", ch);

        printf ("Now try to read file using fscanf()\n");
        ch = fscanf (fptr, "%s", str);
        printf ("fscanf() return value, ch : %d\n", ch);

        printf ("Resetting the file pointer to the start of file\n");
        rewind (fptr);  // This will reset the pointer to the start of file
        printf ("Reading file..\n");

        while ((ch = fscanf (fptr, "%s", str)) == 1) {
                printf ("%s", str);
        }

        printf ("\nch : %d\n", ch);
        fclose (fptr);

        return 0;
}
```

The content of file reading in the above program:

```
Hello Vilho..
How are you!
```

Output:

```
Number of lines in file: 2
ch : -1
Now try to read file using fscanf()
fscanf() return value, ch : -1
Resetting the file pointer to the start of file
Reading file..
HelloVilho..Howareyou!
ch : -1
```

Here you can see, the first `ch : -1` indicate that the file pointer is at `EOF` and if you try to read you will get `EOF` because there is nothing left to read. After resetting file pointer, you can see `fscanf()` is able to read file.

You should not use `while (!feof(file))`. Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong).